# После переопределения метода QSqlTableModel.data() не удаляются записи из БД

Tags: pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

Проблема заключается в том, что после того как я переопределил метод data() в QSqlTableModel, в случае добавления в БД записи в которой одно из полей будет пустое (Null) эту запись нельзя удалить из таблицы (и из БД), если не переопределять метод data() все работает, запись с полями Null удаляется , методом проб и ошибок я дошел до того что сделал поля в таблице NOT NULL, тогда проблема не проявляется. Хотелось бы разобраться почему так происходит и что я делаю не правильно. Буду безмерно благодарен за ответ))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

````
import datetime
import sys

import qdarktheme
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QItemDelegate

from ui_app import Ui_Form


class TableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def set_header(self):
        self.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Имя")
        self.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Пол")
        self.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Возраст")
        self.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Счет")
        self.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Дата")

    def data(self, idx, role=None):
        value = super().data(idx, Qt.DisplayRole)
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            if idx.column() == 4:
                return QtGui.QIcon("assets/calendar.png")
            if idx.column() == 1:
                if value == "мужской":
                    return QtGui.QIcon("assets/ok.png")
                if value == "женский":
                    return QtGui.QIcon("assets/false.png")
        elif role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            if idx.column() == 4:
                return QtGui.QColor("green")
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if idx.column() == 2 or idx.column() == 3:
                return Qt.AlignCenter
        return super().data(idx, role)


class ItemDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        column = index.column()
        if column == 0:
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent)
            return editor
        elif column == 1:
            editor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent)
            editor.addItems(["мужской", "женский"])
            return editor
        elif column == 2:
            editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
            editor.setMaximum(100)
            return editor
        elif column == 3:
            editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
            editor.setMaximum(100000)
            return editor
        elif column == 4:
            editor = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(parent=parent, calendarPopup=True)
            editor.setDate(datetime.datetime.now())
            return editor


class WindowApp(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Приложение")
        self.setFixedSize(560, 500)
        self.con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.con.setDatabaseName("app_db.db")
        self.con.open()
        self.model = TableModel()
        self.model.setTable("users")
        self.model.select()
        self.model.set_header()
        self.tableView.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(self.tableView))
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.add_record)
        self.btnDel.clicked.connect(self.del_record)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_record(self):
        self.model.insertRow(self.model.rowCount())
        self.model.submit()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def del_record(self):
        current_row = self.tableView.currentIndex().row()
        self.model.removeRow(current_row)

        self.model.select()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qss = """QDateEdit::drop-down{image:url('assets/calendar.png');}"""
    qdarktheme.setup_theme(custom_colors={"primary": "#00FF7F", "background": "#696969"}, additional_qss=qss)
    window = WindowApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(425, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(Form)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.dateEdit_1 = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Form, calendarPopup=True)

        self.dateEdit_1.setObjectName("dateEdit_1")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dateEdit_1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.dateEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Form, calendarPopup=True)
        self.dateEdit_2.setObjectName("dateEdit_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dateEdit_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.btnAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnAdd.setObjectName("btnAdd")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnAdd)
        self.btnDel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnDel.setObjectName("btnDel")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnDel)
        self.btnFiltre = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btnFiltre.setObjectName("btnFiltre")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnFiltre)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "MyApp"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "с"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "по"))
        self.btnAdd.setText(_translate("Form", "Добавить"))
        self.btnDel.setText(_translate("Form", "Удалить"))
        self.btnFiltre.setText(_translate("Form", "Фильтр"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```


BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "name"  TEXT,
    "sex"   TEXT DEFAULT 1,
    "old"   INTEGER,
    "score" INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    "date"  TEXT
);
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES ('Николай','мужской',23,4235,'2023-07-06');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES ('Ирина','женский',24,18,'2023-07-07');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES ('Юлия','женский',16,5575,'2023-07-08');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES ('Степан','мужской',16,0,'2023-07-08');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES ('Федор','мужской',27,5555,'2023-07-10');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES ('Игорь','мужской',30,0,NULL);
COMMIT;
````

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `ui_app.py` и скрипт для для создания БД с нужными таблицами

Comment: дополнил свой вопрос  кодом  ui_app.py и скриптом  для для создания БД

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184432/qsqltablemodelremoverow-does-not-delete-row-in-sqlite-database Нашел похожий случай "причина была в переопределенном data()методе в QSqlTableModelпотомке. record()требуется метод data(index, Qt::EditRole)" но понимания это не добавило, как все же стоит поступать если необходимо как либо декорировать данные, переопределение data() это единственный путь?